# how to integrate two apps (mainloop) together in python

Tags: python, multi-touch, kivy

hi i am working on a VR engine "vizard" it has (like any other game engine) its mainloop, i want to integrate it with a multi-touch framework "kivy" which has its own mainloop , is it possible to do so?
and if you can help me finding references about this topic
thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other thing to do is check each library you want to use, and see if it is possible to go without using their native mainloop - you will have to build a mainloop yourself which takes care of calling an "execute pending events" in each of then. Since you are writting your mainloop yourself, this is the way to go.

IF there is no documented way to do it, you should check the source of the other library and re-implement its mainloop inside yours - even if only for proof-of-concept purposes. And open a feaure request on the "kivy" project for being able to use it without a mainloop.

Ah, checking the docs on kivy, I see you can easily inherit their eventloopbase and incorporate  it in your own mainloop:
http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.base.html - your lucky day.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, but you should not do it.
Simply open up the source, get the code for the two main loops and stitch it together.

The results will probably be broken, though.